# Reordering Assets

Tags: pixelandtonic, assets

Is there a way to reorder assets using the Assets plugin?

I want to allow the client to upload a series of files and then choose which order to display them on the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change the order of items in Assets as this is mainly intended as a global asset management addon and not particularly linked to display in front-end templates. You will probably be better off doing this in a Channel Entry where you pull in your assets and then set things like an order on the output.

[Matrix](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix) (also by Pixel & Tonic) will help you to do this where you can place each asset in it's own row providing a way to order them. [Matrix multi-upload](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix-multi-upload) will also provide an easier way for users to upload a batch of files at a time whilst actually creating that entry saving switching back and forth.

Alternatively you could use something such as [Channel Images](http://www.devdemon.com/channel_images) where you're doing much the same thing and pulling in assets into a channel entry with the option to set ordering and various other options before saving.